# C# Windows Forms: How the Control is added to the Form under InitializeComponent() without Controls.Add

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, controls, addition

C# Windows Forms: I was creating an test application using visual studio, i dragged a button on the form and created a an button_click event, when i debugged my application i found that 
"button" displayed on the form, even though i have not added my button to the form using "this.Controls.Add(button)". 
I have also checked the InitializeComponent() method under "filename.Designer.cs", there also "this.Controls.Add(button)" line was missing.

My doubt is: when debugged how the Control(button) automatically added to the form, without "this.Controls.Add(button)" instruction.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you looked closely enough? I'm pretty sure there *is* a call to Controls.Add in InitializeComponents, otherwise it wouldn't work...

Comment: Was it added to another container within the form?  (e.g. a Panel)

Comment: That's wired ,i had also a situation while working with Visual Studio 2010 and 2008 and changed the clock backward it Runn's the Application but without updates ,even if i wrote code it won't update it .

Comment: Sorry there was some mistake from my side, Ignore this post. Request the moderator to delete this post. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It does add it, it's in the "Windows Form Designer generated code" region.

```
#region Windows Form Designer generated code
// Removed to slim...
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // Removed to slim...
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    // Removed to slim...
    this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    // Removed to slim...
}

#endregion
```

Comment: The missing controls, I suppose that for some reason the code was deleted that puts them into the form's ControlCollection which is accessd via the property Form.Controls.

Comment: @VkTt If the line was deleted that added the Control to the Form then the Control would not appear on the Form.

Comment: Sorry there was some mistake from my side, Ignore this post.